# Unite all columns in tibble with tidyr

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I want to unite all the columns in a tibble into one for later processing. Whenever I attempt to do this, I get the error

> Error in if (!after) c(values, x) else if (after >= lengx) c(x, values) else c(x[1L:after],  :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The [tidyr:unite documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/unite.html) says you can do this by not specifying any columns. Here's a toy example:

```
ex <- as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 4))
ex
unite(ex, 'new')
```

Am I just missing some tidyverse subtlety or...?

Comment: You could use `dplyr::everything()` to reference the columns, e.g. `as_tibble(matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 4)) %>% unite(new, everything())`, though this all seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: ...though the docs do seem out of date. It may be a product of the rlang switchover, but regardless is worth a GitHub issue if none exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I believe you need to specify the columns even if you want to combine all of them.

To do this, you can just use 1:x where x is the last column number, you don't need to write them all out. For example, in your code you would put:

```r
unite(ex, new, 1:4, sep="")
```

Remember to put the sep= argument in as well - sep="" means they'll be joined together with no gaps, but sep="." means there will be a dot in between.

Hope that is still of use!

edit: to make it easier to use the column numbers instead of names, you can use ncol() to find the number of columns to specify, eg ncol(ex) returns 4 in your example.

Answer (score 5):

How about

```
df <- ex %>%
unite(ex,1:ncol(ex),sep=" ")
```